# Scala - Abstract functions in traits

Tags: scala, traits

```
trait Rectangular{
def topLeft:Point
def bottomRight:Point
def left=topLeft.x
def right=bottomRight.x
def width=right-left
//andmanymoregeometricmethods...
}


class Rectangle(val topLeft:Point,val bottomRight:Point)
extends Rectangular{
//othermethods...
}
```

In Rectangular he defines an abstract function and he implements it in class Rectangle with a val in the primary constructor.

Is this a special case in traits? Is this expected behavior?

Previously he describes that only def's can override def's. But in this case a val implements an abstract function, which is really strange.

Comment: Who is 'he' ? Is this a book excerpt ?

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Scala-Comprehensive-Step---Step/dp/0981531644/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1347900072&sr=8-1&keywords=SCALA

Comment: If I were you, I'd stay away from that book. Not only is it wrong (or at the very least misleading) about being able to override `def`s with `val`s, the author is also obviously confused about the difference between methods and functions. There are no functions, neither abstract nor otherwise in the code snippet above, there are only methods. Considering that the distinction between methods and functions is *fundamental* in Scala, that seems to be a *huge* mistake.

Comment: probably a mistake on my side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a `val` is actually syntactic sugar for defining a private variable and a public getter method with the same name, so a `val` basically includes a `def`.  When you override a `def` with a `val`, the compiler uses the getter method as the function that overrides the `def`.  You can also override a `def` with a `var`, which defines both a getter and a setter method (though I generally wouldn't consider such behavior "good" code).

Using `def` do define abstract properties allows the implementor to choose whether they want to use `val`, `var`, or `def`.

So, if the author claims that only `def` can override `def`, that is incorrect (perhaps it was the case in an early version of Scala?).

Comment: I read another book from my friend so I am not 100% sure where I read it. Probably it was just a mistake made by me. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I never read that bok (shame on me). But this is wrong. You can override a `def` with a `val` or a `lazy val`. This pattern is very common.

To avoid weird behavior, it is highly recommended to avoid abstract `val`.